# How to handle concurrency in an ASP.Net WebSite? (auctioneer site)

Tags: asp.net

my problem is follow:

I have an auctioneer site, in which many different objects will be auctioneerd.

My problem is very simple to clear for an more experience user I thinK. How I can handle business and database logic without opened a site or them?

My problem is to say directly, if nights at 3 no user is on the site, the winner (e.g.) must be set - if a page is opened or not.

So I need some kind of "every 2 seconds, do this method" - without opened a site.

My idea was a sepereate application which uses the same business and database-layer as the asp.net page and let this run at the server. Is that a good or bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separate process (scheduled app or Windows service) is the only reliable way you can achieve this.

Using the same BLL and DAL are exactly the right thing to do too.

Check out this article on windows services http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984074(VS.71).aspx

Comment: So, to add a lil bit theory before I go and read it: I will have an a windows service which is running on my server. These service handle all logic which is neccesary for the auctions (e.g. automatic bids / set a winner / set a ending auction) ?

Comment: Correct, and your web pages are just a view into the data being processed by the service

Answer (score 0):

To let every user query the database every 2 seconds would create unnecessary traffic on your site, which is not a good idea. (users tend to refresh the page many times just before the auction closes anyway)

My thoughts: 
Add a date to the auction when it closes.
The last user that places a bid is always the winner, and you can't place bids after 3 am (the date the auction closes), so if you visit the site after 3 am (you can't place a bid and) the winning user is displayed. If somebody opens the site just before 3 am and places a bid after 3 am your business logic should check the date of the bid and deny it.. (also: users might live in different timezones so consider displaying the server time on your site). 
Setting the date to 'now' would close the auction immediately.

You can also add javascript to refresh the page if your clock passes the hour or something like that. (or use the number of seconds left before the auction closes in a setTimeout function or metarefresh)

Comment: I'm sorry but that all happens before, the quesion here is only a snippet of my problem: I have the clock in javascript, I can't have a end-date of different design-reasons, like you say. The biggest reason is the automatic bid: How to handle, when not in a service?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with automatic bid... Who's is doing the bidding then? If nobody bids the item would not have been sold right?
otherwise a service or scheduled task would be your only option.